# Using and routing Less file in the layout.cshtml in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, less

I've used [a template for admin section (bootstrap admin template)](https://github.com/puikinsh/Bootstrap-Admin-Template) in my project and installed it from `Bower` and I've applied `ASP.NET Core 2`.

When I run the project, I get an error that is:

> FileError:
>   'http://localhost:52125/lib/bootstrap-admin-template/public/assets/less/theme.less'
>   wasn't found (404)
>
> in theme.less

But the file, `theme.less`, exists in the path!! I don't know why browsers cannot recognize the file.

For routing the `theme.less` file I did:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="~/lib/bootstrap-admin-template/public/assets/less/theme.less">
```

How can I fix this problem?

[image: The error]

[image: Path of theme.less file]

[image: Tree Structure Of Files and Folders]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587765/processing-less-file-on-client-in-asp-net-project.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49611852/1817640

Comment: @seven-phases-max :   In ASP.NET Core 2, there is no web.config file.Then that solution is not useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?tabs=aspnetcore2x#non-standard-content-types) on the StaticFiles middleware:

> If the user requests a file of an unknown file type, the static file middleware returns a HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.

That seems to be what's happening here. If you want to serve less then you need to [add a mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?tabs=aspnetcore2x#fileextensioncontenttypeprovider) for it:

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".less"] = "plain/text";

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

Comment: +rep thx bro you saved my day !!! I tried more than 10 different solutions, but yours worked .... thanks agian

Comment: thanks! note: in a Blazor Server App, you also need to leave in the default call to `app.UseStaticFiles();`, or else you get an HTTP 404 error, when loading `_framework/blazor.server.js`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `Less` files can not be used directly in `asp.net core 2` projects. It must first be compiled.
In this link you can figure out that how be compiled a `Less` file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/less-sass-fa